# image not uploading properly when uploading from ios device camera in php

Tags: php, ios, image-uploading

I am creating a project in codeigniter in which user can upload his profile image. I am using image library to upload it. When I am uploading image using camera in IOS device, image uploaded with some greyed out area. Code in library is

```
function createImage($iMageName,$folderName){
$width = 500; $height = true;
$data=base64_decode($iMageName);
$f = finfo_open();
$mime_type = finfo_buffer($f, $data, FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
$image = imagecreatefromstring($data);
$height = $height === true ? (ImageSY($image) * $width / ImageSX($image)) : $height;
$output = ImageCreateTrueColor($width, $height);
$imgThumb=uniqid().strtotime(date("Y-m-d H:i:s")).'.jpg';
$imageName=$folderName.$imgThumb;
$fullpath=FCPATH.$imageName;
ImageCopyResampled($output, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, ImageSX($image), ImageSY($image));
imagejpeg($output, $fullpath, 90);
return $imageName;
}
```

Working fine for web and android device but problem in ios device, see uploaded image [image]

Answer (score 0):

I have also face the same issue. 
Problem will occurs in following condition:

1. file size. Please validate the file size.
2. Please write the below code and check that it's working.

   ```
    function createImage($iMageName,$folderName){
         ini_set ('gd.jpeg_ignore_warning', 1);
         $width = 500; $height = true;
         $data=base64_decode($iMageName);
         $f = finfo_open();
         $mime_type = finfo_buffer($f, $data, FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
         $image = @imagecreatefromstring($data);
         $height = $height === true ? (ImageSY($image) * $width / 
         ImageSX($image)) : $height;
         $output = @ImageCreateTrueColor($width, $height);
         $imgThumb=uniqid().strtotime(date("Y-m-d H:i:s")).'.jpg';
         $imageName=$folderName.$imgThumb;
         $fullpath=FCPATH.$imageName;
         @ImageCopyResampled($output, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, 
         $height, ImageSX($image), ImageSY($image));
         imagejpeg($output, $fullpath, 90);
         return $imageName;
     }
   ```

Thanks , This will helpfull for you